# Angular JS encoded double quotes not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ngInit to pass variables from PHP to my Angular JS Controller.
In some situations the passed string might contain encoded '"' (Double quotes `&quot;`)

```
<div data-ng-controller="UserController" data-ng-init='init({"test":"&quot;My Test Input&quot;"})'>
</div>
```

But when this happens I am getting the following error in Angular JS :
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/syntax?p0=My&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=16&p3=init(%7B%22test%22%3A%22%22My%20Test%20Input%22%22%7D)&p4=My%20Test%20Input%22%22%7D)

Please help

Comment: Use single quote :- init({"test":' "My Test Input " '})

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div data-ng-controller="UserController" data-ng-init='init({"test":"\"My Test Input\""})'>
```

Comment: The problem here is that the data is user generated. I am using 
    `htmlspecialchars(trim($data), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` in PHP to enter the data to the database and this is being loaded to Angular JS from PHP using the ngInit as shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improper use of `ng-init` and you should run your code in controller instead

**[From docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)**

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: I am actually a newbie in Angular JS. What do you think is the best way to pass data from PHP to a controller in Angular JS ? Till now I was using ngInit.

Comment: Use $http to call backend or worst case pass to variable in script tag and access that variable from controller